# Inject SVN revision to a variable

Tags: java, svn, ant

Is there a way to inject the current SVN number in a Java variable? I want every class to have a private static variable which holds the SVN revision value?

Comment: Why would you need that? If the the revision is added, wouldn't that increase the revision then, since it's not the exact same state as the working copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right answer is not keywords, but

- using SubWCRev,
- storing in repo SubWCRev templates
- processing templates into  real code by build-system

When instead of path to WC path to single file used in SubWCRev call, $WCREV$ from template expanded to revision of last modification for file, not global last revision for repo

```
char *Revision   = "$WCREV$";
```

will be converted in readable, nice

```
char *Revision   = "298";
```